# create a named range for various ranges across the workbook in excel

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I googled a lot on to creating a named range for various cells/ranges distributed across the worksheets in a workbook but I could not get any thing promising. Nevertheless, there are many tutorials available and I also experimented on my system and found that ranges/cells on the same sheet can be combined and given a common name.

My question to all is that if it is really impossible to create a named range for cells/ranges distributed across the workbook? I would appreciate if someone can give some hints on this.

Thanks.

Shakti

Answer (score 0):

A Named range can be assigned to any group of cells on a **single worksheet.**

Comment: Thanks. But Even I had the same opinion. I need across the sheets. :(